# counter function in python

Tags: python

```py
from collections import counter
from itertools import combinations

count=counter()

for row in df['grouped']:
    row_list=row.spilt(',')
    count.upadate(counter(combinations(row_list,2)))
    print(count)
```

```
ImportError Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[77], line 1
----> 1 from collections import counter
      2 from itertools import combinations
      4 count=counter()

ImportError: cannot import name 'counter' from 'collections'
```

Comment: It's `Counter` not `counter` https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html

Comment: use an editor that flags this type of typos

Answer (score 1):

This works (uppercase C):

```py
>>> from collections import Counter
>>>
```